# Creating Core Foundation classes

Tags: c, objective-c, polymorphism, core-foundation

Since I can't seem to find any documentation on this subject, is it possible to create your own Core Foundation "class"? (classes as in ones that can be used with CFRetain() and CFRelease) I want to take advantage of the polymorphic capabilities and object inspection built into Core Foundation without the overhead of Objective-C or creating my own object hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be forewarned: I believe that Core Foundation doesn't have true inheritance without Objective-C loaded, and with Objective-C loaded you'll get the (minor) associated slowdowns anyway.

There probably won't be any documentation on it, but it might be possible. It certainly won't be clean. Try browsing through the [CF-Lite source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.18/) (link is for Mac OS X 10.5.7) to get a feel for the framework's implementation.

Note that if the overhead of Objective-C you mention is the overhead of message invocation, there are a great many ways to optimize it (for example, the [`-instanceMethodForSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-instanceMethodForSelector_) method). You're very likely to spend more time trying to worm your way into the Core Foundation framework than you are trying to optimize Objective-C code to bring it up to speed.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the CF-lite package, and it seems that it's basically not possible to make your own CF types without using undocumented/private functions :(
Looks like I'll end up using good ol' Obj-C and IMP caching.

Comment: If you really need, you can write static C-style wrappers for Objective-C objects via `IMP` caching and direct ivar access… heck, I'm pretty sure that in an non-GC environment you can roll your own allocation too.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there are no Core Foundation classes. They are opaque types.